# sending post request to Firebase but getting "Error=MissingRegistration"

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my code. I'm trying to do a firebase post request to send a push to some devices. But the response is returning this: `Error=MissingRegistration`

```
private final String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
private final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type:application/json";
private final String AUTHORIZATION_KEY = "key=myKey";


JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
message.put("to", "/topics/uff");
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("mensagem", "teste");

message.put("data", data);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
request.setHeader("Content-type", CONTENT_TYPE);
request.setHeader("Authorization", AUTHORIZATION_KEY);
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString(), "UTF-8"));
System.out.println(message.toJSONString());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
System.out.println(responseString);
```

The request works when i use the ARC (Advanced Rest Client) for Chrome, and all my devices recieves the notification.

**EDIT:**

message structure:

```
{"data":{"mensagem":"teste"},"to":"\/topics\/uff"}
```

Comment: `MissingRegistration` is usually received when there `to` or `registration_ids` is not used. It seems you're adding it properly though. Can you try and print the value of your `message` before you send it and post the structure here?

Comment: Edited with the message string value! @AL.

Comment: Try editing this part -- `message.put("to", "/topics/uff");` -- to this -- `message.put("to", "\"/topics/uff\"");`

Comment: Same error. I'm also receiving this same error using a token of a specific device.

Comment: This is odd. The code looks okay. I'll take a look around and see if there's something amiss.

Comment: I've found the problem! "Content-Type:application/json" should be "application/json". Thanks for your time @AL..

Comment: Ahaha. Didn't notice that because of the way setHeader for Content-type was being set. Guess it was just a typo. Cheers!

Comment: Hello @MaxFratane I can not call HttpClient in my project. What should I import or which library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download google-services.json from firebase console.

Get a config file for your Android app
To download a config file for an Android app:

Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
Click google-services.json.

Save this file in your app folder of your project.